# How to query fields through an intermediate many to many field?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I use django 1.8 and python 2.

## What I have

I have a model similar to this:

```
from django.db.models import Model

class Person(Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Unit(Model):
    unit_name = models.CharField()

class PersonUnitRelType(Model):
    relation=models.CharField()

class PersonUnitRelation(Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    unit = models.ForeignKey(Unit)
```

I have a form similar to this:

```
from django import forms
from ceres.persons.models import Person, PersonUnitRelType, Unit

class MForm(forms.Form):
    persons = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(Person.objects)
    units = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(Unit.objects)
    relations = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(PersonUnitRelType.objects)
```

I have a view similar to this:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render

from .forms import MessageForm
from ceres.persons.models import Person, PersonUnitRelType, Unit

def messages(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MessageForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            persons = form.cleaned_data['persons']
            persons_list = [p.name for p in persons]

            relations = form.cleaned_data['relations']
            for relation in relations:
                #TODO: Add all persons in 'relation' to persons_list

            units = form.cleaned_data['units']
            for unit in units:
                #TODO: Add all persons in a unit witch have a 'relation' to persons_list.
            return HttpResponseRedirect("./")
    else:
        form = MForm()

    context = {
        'form': form
    }

    return render(request, 'foo.html', context)
```

## What I want

I want to add all names of persons to a list, whether they are selected direct, by a relation, or by a unit witch has a relation. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is the code I added:

```
        relations = form.cleaned_data['relations']
        for relation in relations:
            unit_persons = Person.objects.filter(personunitrelation__unit=relation)
            for unit_person in unit_persons:
                persons_list = [p.name for p in persons]

        units = form.cleaned_data['units']
        for unit in units:
            relation_persons = Person.objects.filter(personunitrelation__PersonUnitRelType=relation)
            for relation_person in relation_persons:
                persons_list = [p.name for p in persons]
```